# Windows Porting to x64: MFC x86 DLL implementing OLE Automation for MS Word, Access, DAO

Tags: c++, windows, x86, activex, porting

Porting to x64: MFC x86 DLL implementing OLE Automation for MS Word, Access, DAO

I have an app written several years ago that I am porting to x64.
It consists of a VB.Net GUI using .Net 1.1 and several unmanaged C++ DLL's.

Updating the program went well. The VB.Net program runs well on .Net 4.0 and all the DLL's, except one, run fine as 64 bit DLL's. For the DLL that doesn't run as 64 bit I created a stub with that just returns SUCCESS for every function call.

The DLL that I have trouble with as 64 bit uses MFC and creates MS Word documents using OLE automation and updates an Access database using DAO.

Since MS Word and DAO are only available on 32 bit I created a COM server using a DLL Surrogate to run the code. The issue I am concerned with is using pointers to pass parameters back and forth.

Here is an example C++ prototype I am using:

```
DWORD dtmDBaseToTags
    ( IN const struct UserData_t * pzUserData
    , IN struct DataTag_t* pzDataTag
);
```

This function uses the names in pzDataTag to pull data from the Access database and put it into the struct pzUserData.

I don't think this will work over a COM / ActiveX boundary.

How can I access memory in a 32 bit process using a 64 bit pointer?

Will the ActiveX COM Server DLL be able to access the 64 bit memory?

What is the best course of action to take to port this code to 64 bit?

Comment: Well, you'll need to make it work across a COM apartment if you want to use a surrogate.  That requires describing those structs in IDL or writing a custom marshaller.  Do consider that this code expired about 10 years ago, maybe time to retire it.

Comment: I'm doing this for a big company. I wrote the code myself and the customer now wants to use it to process very big files so we are porting it to 64 bit. I have the analysis working, just the reports and database are hanging me up. I am mostly concerned that the pointers won't work going from 64 to 32 bit.